# Mid-80s cartoon with 4-5 robots with "special powers" to zap things; had a scene with a kraken chase on an ice world

Tags: story-identification, tv, cartoon, robots

Does anyone remember a cartoon with 4-5 humanoid robots on Saturday morning in the mid-80s?  As far as I can remember, they had "powers" to zap things and maybe fly but I don't remember much of the story/plot/enemies/powers.

I don't remember humans in the show.

One scene I remember was the were on some ice world and were being chased by this huge polar kraken type monster.  They got cornered at the edge of this ice sheet and some water.  One of the robots (the leader I guess) asked if someone had any power to do anything.  They all looked at each other and one of the female robots said she did and zapped the ice sheet so they floated away from the kraken.  However, since all of them ran out of power, they couldn't do anything except stand on the ice sheet and float in the water.

I don't remember anything after this scene, probably because my parents shut off the TV, or I'm just that old.

It's also possible I caught the re-runs of it, so it's possible it's late 70s or early 80s.

Comment: Were there humans in the show?

Comment: @DoctorWho22, I don't remember humans but thanks for your answer. It's better than where I was yesterday which was no name of the show.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think it's possible that the show you mentioned could be [*The Mighty Orbots*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mighty_Orbots) (1984).

[image: show still with a big robot]

Bo the female robot looks like this and is described to have elemental powers.

> Bo – One of the three female robot team members she is most outgoing,
>   assertive and confident female on the team. Sometimes she likes to
>   play practical jokes, but at times they can backfire (like when she
>   removed Crunch's appetite chip, only to have it broken when they
>   needed it in the episode "Trapped on The Prehistoric Planet"). She is
>   a caring soul and will do what she can to support her team mates. She
>   has the ability to manipulate the elements – fire, water, wind, etc. –
>   to use in a myriad of offensive and defensive effects (whirlwinds,
>   water geysers, etc.).
>
> Bo's primary colors are pale yellow and orange. When forming the
>   gestalt form of Mighty Orbots, she transforms in the left arm, which
>   forms a hand after it is connected to the main body. Through her
>   connection, she can channel her elemental powers throughout the body
>   of Mighty Orbots.

[image: two female looking yellow robots]

Comment: Hmmm... I've never heard of this, was it good?

Comment: @DoctorWho22, thx for the answer. I THINK this is it but I'm not 100% sure. I found a couple episodes on YT but didn't find the scene I remembered/described above. In any case, it's still fun to reminisce.  =)   Thanks to the community for their excellent memory too. I was reading some other posts about other old shows that I remember from my childhood  =)

Comment: @22ndCenturyFza For an early 80s toon that was animated in Japan in a comic book american style, it was quite good.The voice acting was decent, and Robots had more "human personality", and the planetoid bad guy was scary as hell! What I most remember was Ono being the "watchful mother hen of the orbots" and how she actually managed to change into a human once. The only issue I had was they never explained how the Orbots grew in size to allow rob and ono to "pilet" them in their combined mecha form.